# How to I fix the error when search is not exact match

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a run time error for type mismatch when the text in textbox6 doesnt exactly match the data from Column A

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim icsws As Worksheet
    Dim rsdws As Worksheet
    Dim chkshotnumber As Long
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim icsrnum As Long
    Dim firstaddress As String
    Dim control As Long
    Dim chkshot As Long
    Dim yesno As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set icsws = Sheets("Inverse Check Shots")
    Set rsdws = Sheets("Data")
    
    chkshot = icsws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
               
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 3).Value = TextBox1.Text
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 4).Value = TextBox2.Text
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 5).Value = TextBox3.Text
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 6).Value = TextBox4.Text
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 7).Value = TextBox5.Text
    icsws.Cells(chkshot, 8).Value = TextBox6.Text
    
    chkshotnumber = icsws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp) ' I get error here if TextBox6 doesnt match perfectly
    With Sheets("Data").Columns("A:A")
    
    Set rng = .Find(chkshotnumber)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No Control Points Found Matching"
            GoTo Ende
        Else
runagain:
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = rng.Address
        rnum = rng.Row
        icsrnum = icsws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Do
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 3).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 1).Value
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 4).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 2).Value
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 5).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 3).Value
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 6).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 4).Value
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 7).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 5).Value
       icsws.Cells(icsrnum, 8).Value = rsdws.Cells(rnum, 11).Value
       
    Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And firstaddress <> rng.Address
    End If
    End If
    End With
Ende:
    MsgBox ("Check Shot has been added to Inverse Check Shots Tab")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim chkshotnumber` or `Dim chkshotnumber As Variant`.

Comment: Side note: for `Set rng = .Find(chkshotnumber)`, you want to also specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters.

Comment: @BigBen, would that look like this? Set rng = .Find(chkshotnumber, , xlValues, xlPart)

Comment: My guess would be you'd want `What:=chkshotnumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart`.

Comment: That did fix the run time error, but now I get the message "no control point matching" when it should match part. The data in textbox 6 has a "CP" before numbers... the data it is checking against does not have "CP" just the numbers

Comment: Clearly if textbox6 has `CP` and column A doesn't, then `Find` won't find a match. You should strip out nonnumeric content from the textbox6 data then.